# Searching object in object array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have the following array:

```
const HEROES = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Superman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 5, name: 'Wonder Woman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 6, name: 'Aquaman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 7, name: 'Hulk', squad: 'Avengers' },
];
```

I'm trying to pass another object { id: 5, squad: 'Justice League' } into the array to find the matching object.

for example:

```
findOne(HEROES, { id: 5, squad: 'Justice League' })
```

should return

```
{ id: 5, name: 'Wonder Woman', squad: 'Justice League' }
```

I'm not sure how to start this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Use `find`:

```js
const HEROES = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Superman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 5, name: 'Wonder Woman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 6, name: 'Aquaman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 7, name: 'Hulk', squad: 'Avengers' },
];

const findOne = (arr, query) => {
  const { id, squad } = query;
  return arr.find(({ id: a, squad: b }) => (id != undefined ? a == id : true) && (b != undefined ? b == squad : true));
};

console.log(findOne(HEROES, { id: 5, squad: "Justice League" }));
```

Comment: what if the parameter can only be set as findOne(arr, query). How would you pass in the object?

function findOne(arr, query) {
}

Comment: Add this line as the first line in the function @Jim - `const { id, squad } = query`.

Comment: @Jim Edited my answer to display your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I guess I should have made this more clear, the 'query' parameter is not exactly set to { id: 5, squad: "Justice League" }. This method would work in this instance but if I change the object to just {id: 3} or {name: 'Hulk'} it would fail.

Comment: OK @Jim, I'll fix that.

Comment: @Jim See my fixed answer, it'll ignore if you miss one item from the object (if nothing is passed, it'll return the first object).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a utility library like underscore JS or [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#find). They have just such functionality for that.

From lodash docs:

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36, 'active': true },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40, 'active': false },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1,  'active': true }
];

_.find(users, function(o) { return o.age < 40; });
// => object for 'barney'

// The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
_.find(users, { 'age': 1, 'active': true });
// => object for 'pebbles'
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar Code using `find`

```js
const HEROES = [
{ id: 1, name: 'Captain America', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 2, name: 'Iron Man', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 3, name: 'Spiderman', squad: 'Avengers' },
{ id: 4, name: 'Superman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 5, name: 'Wonder Woman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 6, name: 'Aquaman', squad: 'Justice League' },
{ id: 7, name: 'Hulk', squad: 'Avengers' },
];

const findOne=(arr,obj)=>arr.find(x=>x.id==obj.id&&x.squad==obj.squad);

console.log(findOne(HEROES, { id: 7, squad: 'Avengers' }));
```